# How to use aws nlb with nginx ingress controller for ssl

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, aws-nlb

I have attached AWS ACM provided SSL certificate to NLB. NLB will forward request to nginx ingress. Nginx is giving me the following error. `The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port`.
I have set the following annotation in nginx ingress.

- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: false
- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false

I have set following annotation in nginx ingress service which is running behind NLB.

- service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
- service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "certificate arn"
- service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
- service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this error :

> The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

Change your port configuration in **Nginx** service like, your **target port** in *HTTPS* section should be **http** instead of **https**

```
ports:
  - name: https
    **targetPort: http**
```

Here the annotation for reference

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:ap-southeast-1:xxxxxxx:certificate/8991ftt8-69e0-4e7d-1164-yy0aae19da90v
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
```

Comment: this is working. but when i send http request it is not working. for https request it is working fine. @HarshManvar

Comment: or you might would like to use `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"`

Comment: you can redirect your http traffic to https now so all request coming to http will auto redirect to https as it's working now so. so your ssl termination will be at nlb level. `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"`

Comment: refrence document : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/terminate-https-traffic-eks-acm/